# How to create model rb files for all the tables in Mysql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rake, database-migration

I wrote a simple migration file that creates around ten tables. It all created perfectly. Now I need to create ten equivalent model files in the app/models folder. I can do it manually. But I am wondering if there is any rake task available to do this.

Tips/advise on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically: http://magicmodels.rubyforge.org/magic_model_generator/

Manually: http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=1957164&postcount=2

Comment: bravo!! the first link is exactly what i was looking for!! thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a model and migration using the same rails model generator. This will also create a unit test and fixtures.

Rails 2.3.x:

```
script/generate model Person name:string
```

Rails 3.0.x

```
rails g model Person name:string
```

You can also use the following options (taken from Rails 2.3.8 and might have changed in 3.0)

```
Options:
  --skip-timestamps    Don't add timestamps to the migration file for this model
  --skip-migration     Don't generate a migration file for this model
  --skip-fixture       Don't generation a fixture file for this model
```

Comment: Thanks for putting the options available. These are always good to know